# Glossary with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I´d like to make a glossary. It should looks like:

Index-Nav
0-9 | A **B** C ... **M** ... X Y Z

**B**
BMW

**M**
Mercedes
...

**ALL** entries from index-nav (A-Z, O-9) should be visible in a `<ul>` and should linked to the content anchor (only if content isn´t empty). Entry without content should get an additional CSS class.

My code (thanks to @Mridul Aggarwal) shows just entries in index-nav when there is content, too.

Sorry, I´m not an english native speaker.

#### page-my-custom-post-type.php

```
<?php

$index = 0;
$terms = get_terms('marke');
$range = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'Z'));

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {

    if(ord($range[$index]) <= ord(strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)))) {
        while($range[$index] != strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1))) {
            echo '<li>'. $range[$index] . '</li>';
            $index++;
        }
        $index = strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1));
        echo "<li><a href='" . "#" . glossar_ . $index . "' />$index</a></li>";
        $index++;
    }

}
echo '</ul>';
?>

    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cpt_auto', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'marke',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array($term->slug)
            )
        )
    );

    // ============================= OUTPUT ==============================
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
        the_content();

    endwhile;

 echo "<a href='" . "#" . "' />topFooter</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = 0;
$terms = get_terms('marke');
$range = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'Z'));

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {

    if(ord($range[$index]) <= ord(strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)))) {
        while($range[$index] != strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1))) {
            echo '<li>'. $range[$index] . '</li>';
            $index++;
        }
        $index = strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1));
        echo "<li><a href='".get_term_link($term)."' />{$range[$index]}</a></li>";
        $index++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, again. I became for this line: `while($range[$index] != strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)) {` this message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'`

Comment: while is missing the closing `)`. I'll correct it above

Comment: I chance my code above, too. Now failed output from the cpt_auto. It will just show  a "B"?

Comment: i changed the markup here, it had a small problem. What you mean by "failed output from cpt_auto"?

Comment: I mean that nothing will be show on the page without "B" and the page will not stop to load.